# Intermediate value is not iterable reactJS error

Tags: reactjs, node.js, console

I am trying to create a  component with ant design (https://ant.design/components/tabs), but keep getting the same console error for the last item of the list

```
    ...(ticket
      ? menuEntities?.map((m: any) => {
          return {
            key: `entry_${m.id}`,
            label: m.name,
            children: <MenuEntityContent menu={m} desk_id={ticket.desk_id} />
          }
        })
      : [])
```

```
            <Tabs
              className="ticket-tab"
              defaultActiveKey="1"
              type="line"
              size="middle"
              items={items}
            />
```

console output:
`Uncaught TypeError: (intermediate value)(intermediate value)(intermediate value) is not iterable`

I think it's probably being caused by something to do with the .map, because it is the only one that it appears, but I really don't know what the error is trying to say when it mentions that there's an intermediate value, or even what it is trying to "iterate", if you know the answer to any of my many questions let me know lol

React: v16.13.1
Node: v20.0.0

Tried changing some stuff around, nothing of special notice.
I just want my console clean.

Comment: What is the value `menuEntities` when you get the error?

Comment: 0: {id: 1, organization_id: 1, name: 'teste', applied_in: 'ticket', description: '1231123', …}
length: 1
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)

Comment: I can't see why that value would produce an error. Much less the error you report.

Comment: life has many mysteries

Comment: "*I really don't know what the error is trying to say when it mentions that there's an intermediate value, or even what it is trying to "iterate"*" working backwards - it will iterate the value you're trying to spread with `...`. In your code that value is `(ticket ? menuEntities?.map((/* ... */) : [])`. Now back to the first part of what you said - since the value is *an expression* that's reported as an intermediate value. Because it's not something more concrete like a variable, e.g. `...foo` would report that `foo` is not iterable.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Is the variable a React State? Maybe it is not available to iterate in time when running the .map function. Can it be?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).